# Error: AES Encryption key: invalid conversion from ‘char*’ to ‘unsigned char’

Tags: c++, c, encryption, aes

I'm trying to encrypt with AES using `aes.h` 
I'm having trouble assigning a previous generated Encryption Key.

```
const static unsigned char aes_key[]={(unsigned char*)strKey};
```

I got the following error:  `error: invalid conversion from ‘char*’ to ‘unsigned char’ [-fpermissive]
   const static unsigned char aes_key[]={(unsigned char*)strKey};`

```
#include <openssl/aes.h>
#define KEYSIZE 16

int main()
{

        char key[KEYSIZE];
        char strKey[(KEYSIZE*2)+1]={0};

        for (int i = 0; i< KEYSIZE; i ++){
            key[i] = (unsigned char) rand()%256;  
            printf("%.2x\n", (unsigned char)key[i]);  
            sprintf(&strKey[i*2], "%.2x",  (unsigned char) key[i]);



        }

        printf("\n");
        printf( "%s\n", strKey);



        const static unsigned char aes_key[]={(unsigned char*)strKey};

        /* AES-128 bit CBC Encryption */
        AES_KEY enc_key;
        AES_set_encrypt_key(aes_key, sizeof(aes_key)*8, &enc_key);
        AES_cbc_encrypt(aes_input, enc_out, sizeof(aes_input), &enc_key, iv, AES_ENCRYPT);


return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is initialize the array `aes_key` with another array variable `strkey`. This is not allowed directly in C.

What you can do instead is

```
int len = strlen(strKey);
const static unsigned char aes_key[len+1];
strcpy(aes_key, str_key);
```

Comment: "What you are trying to do is initialize the array aes_key with another array variable strkey". It was indeed the intention of the OP to do so. But strictly speaking what he did and what the error says is defining a one element `unsigned char` array and initialising it with a `char *`